# Group by error in hibernate and HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

My HQL query gives me the following error:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: the expression is not an aggregate or GROUP BY columns: CIUDAD2_.ID_PAIS

My query is:

```
return getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("select s.ciudadSede.paisCiudad.idPais AS idPais,"
            + "s.ciudadSede.paisCiudad.nombrePais AS nombrePais,"
            + "s.ciudadSede.idCiudad AS idCiudad,"
            + "s.ciudadSede.nombreCiudad AS nombreCiudad,"
            + "case when s.ciudadSede.valorCiudad = null then s.ciudadSede.paisCiudad.valorPais else s.ciudadSede.valorCiudad end AS valor,"
            + "s.tipoJjoo.descripcionTipo AS descripcionTipoJjoo,"
            + "s.ciudadSede.valorCiudad AS numeroVecesSede "
            + "from Sede s join s.ciudadSede AS c "
            + "group by c.idCiudad").setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SedeDto.class)).list();
}
```

What I want is to group the "Sedes" grouped by city

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want to **`GROUP BY foo`**, that means the query will return a single row for each distinct value of the expression **`foo`**.

SQL requires that *every* expression in the **`SELECT`** list either be an expression included in the **`GROUP BY`** clause, or an *aggregate* function (e.g. `COUNT()`, `SUM()`, `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()`). (There are a few exceptions to that rule such as literals and results of deterministic functions.)

The error indicates that an expression in the `SELECT` list of the query isn't in the `GROUP BY` clause, or isn't an aggregate expression.

---

I'm not sure if you were asking a question, or if you were just giving a status report on your current efforts...

Are you sure you want a **`GROUP BY`** and not an **`ORDER BY`**?

Comment: If you want the number of times a host grouped by s.tipoJjoo.descripcionTipo s.ciudadSede.idCiudad and repeats, the group by clause is:
"group by s.ciudadSede.idCiudad, s.tipoJjoo.descripcionTipo") and would select
+ "Count (s) AS numeroVecesSede"
A greeting and thanks.

Comment: @oscar: Yes, `COUNT()` is an aggregate function, and can be included in the SELECT list of query that includes a `GROUP BY` clause. The error occurs when you add an expression in the SELECT list (which is not an aggregate, and not an expression in the GROUP BY clause, not a literal, or a deterministic function based on expression in the GROUP BY, et al.)